# How to compare 3 different Lists & get the value in c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I send below request & receive the below response.
but in response model only Index is the item identifier, there is no itemcode.

I want to update the discount details of each product in the database,
how can I do this.

P.S I am already having all necessary c# classes for database & other stuff, just help me with getting discount details for each item.
Please help me with whatever that needs write for this like joins, linq, loops..

**Request:**

```
  "Items": [
    {
      "itemcode": 5,
      "price": 600,
      "Index": 1
    },
    {
      "itemcode": 34,
      "price": 970,
      "Index": 2
    }
  ]
}

**Response:**

{
  "Items": [
    {
      "discount": {
        "id": 3,
        "amoumt": 40
      },
      "Index": 1
    },
    {
      "discount": {
        "id": 3,
        "amoumt": 25
      },
      "Index": 2
    }
  ]
}


**Finally it should look like**
{
  "items": [
    {
      "itemCode": 5,
      "discount": {
        "id": 3,
        "amoumt": 40
      }
    },
    {
      "itemCode": 34,
      "discount": {
        "id": 3,
        "amoumt": 25
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I assume `itemcode` is the database id of the item? Do you have C# classes for the JSON structures?

Comment: Yes, I am having all C# classes for json structure, actually it's very complex model, for problem statement I made it short.

Answer (score 1):

I'm understanding that you need to pair each request item with it's corresponding response item, since you need information from both to do the DB update. There are multiple ways to achieve this. On is using [`Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-6.0):

```cs
IEnumerable<(RequestItem, ResponseItem)> pairs = request.Items.Join(
    response.Items,
    reqItem => reqItem.Index,
    resItem => resItem.Index,
    (reqItem, resItem) => (reqItem, resItem));
```

This gives you an enumerable of request/response item pairs that you can iterate over in a list to perform the update.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, you can replace anonymous class with yours

```
    var items1 = (JArray)JObject.Parse(json1)["Items"];
    var items2 = (JArray)JObject.Parse(json2)["Items"];

    var query = from i1 in items1
                 join i2 in items2
                 on (int)i1["Index"] equals (int)i2["Index"]
                 select  new
                 {
                     ItemCode = (int)i1["itemcode"],
                     Discount = new
                     {
                         Id = (int)i2["discount"]["id"],
                         Amount = (int)i2["discount"]["amoumt"],
                     }
                 };
     var items = new { Items = query };
```

test

```
string json =   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

{
  "Items": [
    {
      "ItemCode": 5,
      "Discount": {
        "Id": 3,
        "Amount": 40
      }
    },
    {
      "ItemCode": 34,
      "Discount": {
        "Id": 3,
        "Amount": 25
      }
    }
  ]
}
```